# Zalenium startup: unknown shorthand flag: 'r' in -rm-ti-name

Tags: docker

i try to start Zalenium with the PowerShell and get only this. What am I doing wrong?

> PS C:\Windows\system32> docker run -rm-ti-name zalenium-p 4444:444\ -v/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock\ -v/tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos\ -privileged dosel/zalenium start
>
> unknown shorthand flag: 'r' in -rm-ti-name

This is where I refer to: https://testguild.com/zalenium-guide-video/

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect the first option to `docker run` to be?  It looks like you've combined four separate options together into one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos --privileged dosel/zalenium start
```